# Loop through 2 Arrays and assign a value from one array into each matching objects of second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, lodash

I have 2 Arrays 1.Options and 2.sameAccountArray

```
 options.map((opt, optInd) => {
            sameAccountArray.map((acObj, acInd) => {
                if (opt.optNumber === acObj.optNumber) {
                    console.log(opt.optNumber, acObj.optNumber, acObj.exist, acObj.exist, 'WTF', sameAccountArray);
                    opt.exist = acObj.exist;
                } else {
                    console.log(opt, acObj, opt.optNumber, acObj.optNumber, 'kundi');
                    // opt.exist = false;
                }
                // else {
                //     if (optInd === acInd) {
                //         opt.exist = acObj.exist;
                //     } else {
                //         console.log('elseeee', optInd, acInd,opt.optNumber, acObj.optNumber, opt.exist, acObj.exist);
                //     }
                // }
            });
        });
```

Data Structure of sameAccountArray:

```
{
                    'key': key,
                    'shares': this.no_of_shares[key],
                    'refValue': this.your_reference[key],
                    'exist': false,
                    'accountNumber': extractedAccountNumber, 'optNumber': parseInt(extractedOptionNumber)
                }
```

Option have big fields inside, but we don't need to care about it. options and sameAccountArray have common filed named `optNumber`. I am trying loop through each array and assign a value named `exist` in each object of the options array if optNumber is same. sameAccountArray already has the correct `exist` value, I just need to assign that value to match objects of `options` array. Somehow it's not assigned correctly. Please note that options array and sameAccount Array is not the same length. sameAccountArray has dynamic objects while `options` have a fixed number of elements. Any idea what is going wrong here guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all you have to return something from map function to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options.forEach(opt=>{
    sameAccountArray.forEach(acObj=>{
      if (opt.optNumber === acObj.optNumber) opt.exist = acObj.exist;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You cannot modify your arrays with `map()` function, but only create a new array with the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let sameAccountObject={};

    sameAccountArray.forEach((account)=>{
        sameAccountObject[account.optNumber]=account;
    });

    let result=options.map((option)=>{
        let account=sameAccountObject[option.optNumber];
        if(account){
            option.exist=account.exist;
        }
       return option;
    });
 console.log(result);
```